# How to download files from auto download links using perl

Tags: excel, perl

I'm trying to download an excel file using getstore from LWP::Simple using this code:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple qw(getstore);

$xls_link = "http://linksample.com/this/link/auto-downloads/when-link-is-entered.xls";
$file_dir = "file/directory/filename.xls"
getstore($xls_link, $file_dir);
```

For some reason the file is not downloading. I have used LWP::Simple before with images and they work just fine. The only difference they have with this is that it is an excel file and also the URL auto downloads the file when you enter the URL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *auto download* but it's likely to be done by JavaScript in the downloaded page. What is the file type of the URL? I assume it's not an xls link?

Comment: check manually the link is available

Comment: The link is available, it is one of those link that once you enter it in the URL it would not go to a certain page but will download the file directly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getstore I used WWW::Mechanize instead and also I was getting certification errors from the link

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use IO::Socket::SSL qw();

my $xls_link = "http://linksample.com/this/link/auto-downloads/when-link-is-entered.xls";
my $file_dir = "file/directory/filename.xls"
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(ssl_opts => {
SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
verify_hostname => 0, # this key is likely going to be removed in future LWP >6.04
});

$mech->get("$xls_link");
$mech->save_content("$file_dir");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested might be helpful for your request.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $xls_link = $ARGV[0]; #http://linksample.com/this/link/auto-downloads/when-link-is-entered.xls
if (! head($xls_link)) { print "\nError: Provided weblink not available...!\n";   exit;  }
else
{
    my $file_dir = "c:/file/directory/filename.xls";
    if(-e $file_dir) { print "\nError: Provided Directory/File found...!\n"; exit; }
    getstore($xls_link, $file_dir);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting weblink not available error, does that mean the link is not valid for getstore function?